# How to get top search results and return a random gif using tenor api in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

i was trying to make a gif command using `tenor api` using this function,but in this it just returns one gif everytime so how can i make it like it get the top results and appends it in a list and just get a random gif using `random` module

```
def get_gif(searchTerm):  
    response = requests.get("https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q={}&key={}&limit=1".format(searchTerm, TenorToken))
    data = response.json()
        
    # see urls for all GIFs
    for result in data['results']:
        for media in result['media']:
            return data['results'][0]['media'][0]['gif']['url']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `limit=1`in your api call to a number up to 50 as per: https://tenor.com/gifapi/documentation#endpoints-search

`data["results"]`will then be a list of `GIF_OBJECT`, and you can select a random one of those using `random.choice`:

```
import random
...

...
gif = random.choice(data["results"])
```

You could then return the gif using something like

`return gif['media'][0]['gif']['url']`

Comment: thank you for the explanation but how do i change the limit?

Comment: @MrEagOp In the first line of your function, in the `request.get`function, in the url, there is a parameter called limit.